# Rails: Render pictures depending on the selected option in select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 5.1 project I have model Car, it have some photos upload from gem paperclip, how render photo depending on the selected option in select_tag without reloading the page?

```
select_tag 'Cars', options_for_select(@cars.collect{ |u| [u.car_name, u.id] })
```

Comment: Does the car has a link to the photo? Your need to put a div where you will place the photo. When the car select changes, change the image source in a JavaScript that handles this event.

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript for this. Look at something like [this](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3691-Dynamic-Select-Menus-in-Rails-5). It gets a little more complicated as you'll need to handle loading images on the fly / preloading them.